# Significance of model in arithmetic coding

Tags: information-theory, data-compression

I am trying to understand the concept of arithmetic coding, i understand how the range is subdivided after each character is read from the string. But i am unable to understand why using a more accurate model compresses the string. Whether the model is static/adaptive either way the number of characters in the compressed string would be the same. What am i missing?

Comment: Are you familiar with Huffman coding? That's a much simpler example of the same phenomenon.

Comment: I get huffman coding, but how does the predictive-model affect the efficiency of arithmetic coding? consider a case where a static model is used to predict the next character's probabilities in this case the arithmetic coder will always split the sub interval into equal parts where as if the predictive model is adaptive the next interval would be split into un-equal parts. either case the number of digits in the encoded string would be same right?

Comment: Arithmetic coding is a better version of Huffman coding. See if it makes sense for Human coding. For example, suppose you are sending digits, and you know that the digits alternate in parity. So you also alternate Huffman codes. You save a bit each character.

Comment: In huffman coding, the length of the code is inversely proportional to the probability with which the correspoding symbol occurs, but in arithmetic coding only the interval size in the number line varies according the the predicted probability (consider adaptive model) but still the number of digits in the compressed string would be same as the number of digits produced by a string that is compressed using a static model. So how is the model's accuracy affecting the length of compressed string?

Comment: It’s just not true that the number of digits will be the same. Arithmetic coding is a continuous version of Huffman coding. I suggest finding another source on arithmetic coding, which explains how the output precision is chosen.